# dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found

Tags: bash, macos, homebrew, zsh, recode

I have install `recode` via homebrew and when I executing the commands the error occurred

```sh
$ recode TIS620..u8 LOTUS/Supplement/*.txt
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _rpl_malloc
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/recode/3.7-beta2_1/lib/librecode.0.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _rpl_malloc
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/recode/3.7-beta2_1/lib/librecode.0.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace

[1]    8285 abort      recode TIS620..u8 LOTUS/Supplement/*.txt
```

I am using Mac OS X Big Sur. Any help is appreciated